# Cannot pass a sudo command in AppleScript via Automator

Tags: applescript, sudo, automator

I have an issue with Logi Options+ that causes me to have to kill it via terminal and reopen it. I'm able to run the command via terminal, put in my sudo password then open the app and everything is great again. However, I want to create an Automator script to automate this process. Based on what I've looked up, I've pieced this much together, but I am doing something wrong as I get a syntax error each time Automator tries to run it.

`

```
on run {input, parameters}
    
    tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "pkill -9 logioptions" with administrator privileges
    end tell
    
    return input
end run
```

`

If I take out the "with admin privileges" bit out, it'll run, but then I have to put my password in. I want to automate the whole process.

Comment: I think you're mixing your apples and oranges. `do script` in Terminal is not `do shell script`. The latter supports `with administrator privileges`, the former does not.

Comment: ok how do I fix it? I don't care which one I use as long as it works.

Comment: Per apple, there are two ways: 
[TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG1-HOW_DO_I_GET_ADMINISTRATOR_PRIVILEGES_WITHOUT_PROMPTING_): Include your password within the script or use `sudoers`.